# Why Shift-<Down arrow> does not work in the editor?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am following the 'Learn' lesson of Intellij.

[image]

When I get to `Select several lines with Shift ↓`, I am not able to select any lines.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be due to the presence of the plugin `IdeaVim`. Uninstall and reboot Intellij allows me to use shift + down arrow key again

Answer (score 0):

I think Uninstalling it is not the best idea for those who like vim features, so to anyone who still has the same problem in 2023,

```
set selectmode=key 
set keymodel+=startsel,stopsel,stopselect
```

Adding these two commands to your `.ideavimrc` file will solve the problem.